# How to find consecutive business days in SQL?

Tags: sql, row-number

I need to count consecutive business days and identify members with 14 or more. My dataset would be similar to this:

| Member | Date | Day of Week | Consecutive Days (need to create) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Member 1 | 2/10/23 | Friday | 1 |
| Member 1 | 2/13/23 | Monday | 2 |
| Member 1 | 2/14/23 | Tuesday | 3 |
| Member 1 | 2/17/23 | Friday | 1 |
| Member 2 | 2/2/23 | Thursday | 1 |
| Member 2 | 2/3/23 | Friday | 2 |

I want the first 3 rows for Member 1 to count towards the consecutive days but not the 4th since it was not a consecutive business day (not worried about holidays).

I started off just finding consecutive days with the following code and thought I could adjust it to account for weekends by removing them but I can't figure out a good solution.

```
WITH pre AS
(
    SELECT 
        member, date, 
        DATE_ADD(date, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY member, date)) DateGroup
    FROM 
        dataset1
    GROUP BY 
        member, date
),
pre2 as
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(u.date) startdt,
        MAX(u.date) enddt, 
        a.DateGroup, 
        DATEDIFF(MAX(u.date), MIN(u.date)) + 1 Consecutive_days, 
        u.date, u.member
    FROM 
        pre a 
    JOIN 
        dataset1 u ON u.date = a.date AND u.member = a.member
    GROUP BY 
        DateGroup, u.member
    ORDER BY 
        startdt
)
SELECT 
    startdt, enddt, Consecutive_days, member 
FROM 
    PRE2 
WHERE 
    Consecutive_days >= 14;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.